# scope of attributes initialised using __init__ in python

Tags: python, oop

I want to ask a question about initialised attributes in python.

I wrote the following code about OOP for a Python lesson:

```
# DEFINING THE SIMPLEST POSSIBLE CASE

class User:
    def __init__(self, first, last, age):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age

    # convention for Dunder methods __ __ to go at the top
    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first} {self.last}"
    def initials(self):
        return f"{self.first[0]}.{self.last[0]}"
    def likes(self, thing):
        return f"{self.first} likes {thing}"

user1 = User("Joe", "Smith", 68)
user2 = User("Blanca", "Lopez", 41)

print(user1.likes("Ice cream"))
print(user2.likes("Chips"))
```

I understand the function of this code.

However, from previous understanding of functions, when I need to use the value of a parameter, I need to include it in the parentheses before the function is written out.

I thought that the scope of the instance attributes `self.first`, `self.last` and `self.age` were local to the `__init__` method. This means that when doing:

```
def full_name(self):
    return f"{self.first} {self.last}"
```

I was trying to work out why it wasn't written as:

```
def full_name(self, self.first, self.last):
    return f"{self.first} {self.last}"
```

This specific matter wasn't addressed in the lessons. My interpretation was that the attributes of the instance were available to all the methods we declare after our instantiation, almost as if the attributes were "global" within the class, but I'm still unsure why you only need to pass in `self` rather than `self.first` and `self.last` as I mentioned above.

I know why I need to pass in `self` as we are referring to the object that we are calling our method on, but why do not need the other parameters?

Comment: Read up on [Python Classes and Objects, Section "The self|Class and Instance Variables"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `self.first` you are just accessing an attribute of the `self` object.  So it is redundant to pass in `self, self.first, self.last` in the method, as you can just access the child attributes of the class instance as long as you have the reference to that instance of the class (`self`).